# Git bare - what to backup?

Tags: git, backup, git-bare

I'm sorry if this is covered elsewhere, but I can't find the answer.

I have a bare repo, called bare.git which is the repository from which are cloned the dev repos. It all works well.

I want to know where bare.git gets the source files from. Are they stored as binary files inside the bare.git file structure? I can move bare.git to another location and still clone repos out of it, so the source must, in some way, be portable. Or is it storing absolute network references to the files?

There are three main reasons I want o know this information:

1. We need to know what to backup.
2. My boss wants to know where the source code has gone.
3. We need a current composite version for testing.

Comment: @YourBoss - the magic source code genies have eaten it.

Comment: Git has a sort of database in .git in a normal clone or in repository.git in a bare repository.  The bare repository has no checked out file (which is the definition of a bare repository) so the source files are all in the "database", in objects/??/* or objects/pack/*.  You must back up the entire bare.git.

Comment: @Paddy - you mean the gits ate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your source files are stored as a part of the index inside of bare.git file structure, which is same as you have in .git directory in any of your clones.

So, it's best to backup full bare.git.

You may get current version for testing by cloning your bare repo.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you *not* backup all of the repo?

See [The Git Object Model](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html) and [How Git Stores Objects](http://book.git-scm.com/7_how_git_stores_objects.html).

Comment: Well, I didn't know whether the repo contained the source or just the differences, hence my question. Good links - I hadn't found those.

Answer (score 1):

Backup the whole *bare.git* folder not to miss out, you could always clone it later.

When you wish to test source code, you need to clone it. The article [Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) shows you one way to deal with the issue by *checking out the whole repo after each push to bare.git*, automatically of course. This code is what you should test (unless you'd like to do that before pushing to bare.git, in *pre-commit* or *pre-receive*.